# SQLite Get value from other table

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have a `table1`: `abbr_state, thing1, thing2`

And `table2` with: `state, code (the index), thing3`

So `abbr_state = GA`, while `state = Georgia` and `code = GA`.

Is there anyway I can do a `SELECT` where it's:

`SELECT abbr_state,thing1,thing2 FROM table1 ORDERY BY blah blah blah...`

But make it so that when it does `abbr_state`, it comes from the full state name instead of the abbr?

Comment: The word you're looking for is `JOIN`

Comment: Is there a lookup anywhere in your database (not sure if it's contained in these two tables) which would suggest that `GA is indeed  Georgia`? If not, then unfortunately, with the current setup, you can't.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena yes! There's a code column that acts as the key which is the same as abbr_state. Will update above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that could be used is:

```
SELECT abbr_state, state, thing1, thing2 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
     ON table1.abbr_state = table2.code
ORDER BY blah;
```

You may add any `WHERE` conditions before the `ORDER BY` clause, if the need be. Or, those can even be clubbed in the `JOIN` statement:

```
      ....
      ON table1.abbr_state = table2.code
      AND table1.fielda = 'xyz'
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a ["join"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and to do it you need a "join table" linking the state abbreviations to the states themselves.

The join table might be a table with information about the state.

```
create table states (
    id integer primary key,
    name text unique,
    abbreviation text unique,
    capital text
);
```

Note that I've enforced that state names and abbreviations must be unique. Not only does this make sure that nobody accidentally gives Alaska and Alabama the same abbreviation, but it also sets up an [index](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) to make looking up states by name or abbreviation very fast.

Then you'd join them together using the abbreviation.

```
select states.name
from table1
join states on table1.abbrev_state == states.abbreviation
order by states.name
```

Note that once you have the states table, it's safer and more efficient to store the state ID in table1 than the abbreviation. It's faster to compare numbers than strings, it's guaranteed not to change, and the relationship is documented and enforced with a [foreign key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You will need a way to link those two tables together. Your current structure such as it is, will not work.

```
/* your example */    
select abbr_state, thing1, thing2
from table1

select state, thing3
from table2
```

As mentioned above, you need to join the tables. You will need to add another column on table2:

```
select state, thing3, fk_abbr_state
from table2
```

Then you can join them on the abbreviation

```
select table2.state, table1.thing1, table1.thing2
from table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.abbr_state = table2.fk_abbr_state
```

I hope this helps.